# ListBox in Grid Row with Auto height. Scrollbar is not working

Tags: wpf, scroll, listbox, grid

I have the following grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Height="50" Background="Gainsboro" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Border Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="asdasdfasdf3dfasdf"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Height="60" Background="Aquamarine" Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Why ListBox's scrollviewer is not enabled? Last border is pushed out of a window. If i set the Grid.Row 2 Height to * star - it works nicely. Is it possible to have listbox with scrollviewer in auto height grid row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Auto` makes your control resize as it needs. Therefore your `ListBox` will resize itself to show all its content and the scroll bar will never been shown.

`*` makes your control to take the available size, and it does not grow beyond that.

What you need to do is either define the `MaxHeight` property for the `ListBox` or use `*` as height in `RowDefinition`.

Comment: I was afraid you confirm my presumption. Star is not good because it makes the border with listbox bigger than necessary. MaxHeight is works fine, but to make it fill all available space I have to make calculations in code behind every time windows is resized. I wanted to avoid that, but it seems unavoidable ;)