# Listbox in Grid Row with MaxHeight definded: Scrollbar disabled

Tags: wpf, listbox, grid, scrollbar

I have the following Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="200"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
    <ListBox x:Name="lstAbweichungen" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14"
             ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Visible" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

The scrollbar in the ListBox is visible but not enabled, and the listbox stretches into the invisible area. I want the ListBox not to stretch beyond the 200 and the scrollbar working. Do you see what's wrong? Thanks, Anne

Comment: I already read this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751357/listbox-in-grid-row-with-auto-height-scrollbar-is-not-working)

Comment: it may be a behavior of Grid parent container. what container Grid is located in?

Comment: The Grid is located in a UserControl.

Comment: Have you tried by assigning the height to ListBox?

Comment: It works if I add MaxHeight="200" to the ListBox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the code you supplied I was not able to reproduce the problem.

However, I found that if you place any control (ListBox, ScrollViewer, Grid) within a Stackpanel, ScrollViewer or a Listbox, the controls will behave exactly as you have described.

Does your main grid exist within another control? Maybe the User Control exists within a container such as the ones I have mentioned?

Comment: OK you pointed me to the right direction. The UserControl gets inserted into a grid, which has fixed row height and the UserControl has RowSpan set. And the grid with the fixed row height is inside a window.

Answer (score 0):

Also experienced this odd behavior with the ListBox vertical scrollbar. Maybe a bug. Try move the MaxHeight to the ListBox.

Comment: you should not use the answer section until you are sure for the solution, use comments section to add comments you will be eligible to comment once you cross 50 repute.